# How to access a variable from another function in the same class in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a (beginner) problem, can somebody tell me how i can refactor/rewrite my logic so that i can access the namesSplit variable in the evaluateResult Function?

```
export class ExecutableVariableNode implements IExecutableNode {
execute(treeNode: ExpressionTreeNode, exprData: ExpressionData): any {
    let namesSplit = treeNode.name.split('.');
    let key = namesSplit[0];
    let contextEntry = exprData.contextEntry.find(_x => _x.name === key);

    if (namesSplit.length > 1) {
        this.evaluateResult(contextEntry.value);
    }
}

isPrimitive(test): boolean {
    return typeof test !== 'object';
}


// Get Values
evaluateResult(val) {
    if (this.getType(val) === ExpressionVariableType.OBJECT) {
        return Object.values(val);
    }
    else if (this.getType(val) === ExpressionVariableType.ARRAY_OF_OBJECTS) {
        for (let obs of val) {
            for (let n = 0; n < namesSplit.length; n++) {
                if (namesSplit[n] == Object.keys(obs)) {
                    let result = Object.values(obs);
                    console.log(result);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if (this.getType(val) === LapsExpressionVariableType.ARRAY_OF_PRIMITIVES) {
        throw new StdException('Array of Primitives not allowed!');
    }
    else if (this.getType(val) === LapsExpressionVariableType.PRIMITIVE) {
        throw new StdException('Primtive values not allowed!');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: just move it outside, s.t. it is declared as global member of the class, or pass it as a parameter to evaluateResult

Comment: I‘ve tried that but than I get an error (TS1068) which tells me that I have an unexpected token!

Comment: You Can use a service to share variables 
ex : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297742/sending-variable-from-component-to-service-in-angular-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your variable as global variable, then you can access it within the class like this.

```
export class ExecutableVariableNode implements IExecutableNode {

    namesSplit: any;

    execute(treeNode: ExpressionTreeNode, exprData: ExpressionData): any {
        this.namesSplit = treeNode.name.split('.');
        let key = this.namesSplit[0];
        let contextEntry = exprData.contextEntry.find(_x => _x.name === key);

        if (this.namesSplit.length > 1) {
            this.evaluateResult(contextEntry.value);
        }
    }

    isPrimitive(test): boolean {
        return typeof test !== 'object';
    }


    // Get Values
    evaluateResult(val) {
        if (this.getType(val) === ExpressionVariableType.OBJECT) {
            return Object.values(val);
        }
        else if (this.getType(val) === ExpressionVariableType.ARRAY_OF_OBJECTS) {
            for (let obs of val) {
                for (let n = 0; n < this.namesSplit.length; n++) {
                    if (this.namesSplit[n] == Object.keys(obs)) {
                        let result = Object.values(obs);
                        console.log(result);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (this.getType(val) === LapsExpressionVariableType.ARRAY_OF_PRIMITIVES) {
            throw new StdException('Array of Primitives not allowed!');
        }
        else if (this.getType(val) === LapsExpressionVariableType.PRIMITIVE) {
            throw new StdException('Primtive values not allowed!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it for me!